# how to display different description for each virtual product which was create with configurable products?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, configurable-product

In **Magento 2** , when we create **configurable product** its child product also created, we can provide different description for child products too.

> ```
> > 1. How to access description of each child product on product page?
> > 2. can we make it throw on change of fields , like if we changes color on product 
>      page, so it will show description of that color child product?
> ```

Any help will thank full.

Comment: Try this https://bsscommerce.com/simple-details-on-configurable-product-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer : im using magento 2.0.4

i used '\app\design\frontend\Venustheme\fasony\Magento_ConfigurableProduct\templates\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml' file to get work done.

> some small code you will need to get job work done

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$description=[];
$_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
        foreach ($_children as $child){
            if($child->getDescription())
            {
             // $description array hold each child id and description
             $description[$child->getID()]=$child->getDescription();
            }
        }

//In case if you did't added child product description for some product so they will display main product description
      $description["product"]=$product->getDescription();

//code for product option change: what was this code

 $get=json_decode($block->getJsonConfig($option_txt),true);

$checkOption=[];
 foreach ($get['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
     if($value['code']=='color')
     {
        foreach ($value['options'] as $k => $v) {
$checkOption[$v['id']]=$v['products'][0];

        }
     }
 }
```

//code for product option change end :

```
//some script to use with select option
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery'],function($){
    var checkOption=<?php echo json_encode($checkOption);?>;
    var description=<?php echo json_encode($description);?>;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#attribute90").on('change',function(){
           var id= $(this).val();
           if(description[checkOption[id]])
           {
            //get child product description
           $('div[id="product.info.description"]').html(description[checkOption[id]]);
           }
           else{
            //if child product dont have description show , main product description
           $('div[id="product.info.description"]').html(description["product"]);

           }
        });

   });
});
</script>
```

**full source code of my configurable.phtml file**

```
<?php

  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

  $description=[];

  //get all childrens
  $_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);

  foreach ($_children as $child){
            if($child->getDescription())
            {
            $description[$child->getID()]=$child->getDescription();
            }
        }
        $description["product"]=$product->getDescription();

?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute):?>
        <div class="field configurable required">
            <label class="label" for="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>">
                <span><?php $label=$block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel());
                echo $label; 
                ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        id="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
                        class="super-attribute-select" data-placholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ 
                        echo "$label:";
                    ?>">
                    <option value="">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; 


//code for product option change
 $get=json_decode($block->getJsonConfig($option_txt),true);

$checkOption=[];
 foreach ($get['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
     if($value['code']=='color')
     {
        foreach ($value['options'] as $k => $v) {
$checkOption[$v['id']]=$v['products'][0];

        }
     }
 }
//code for product option change end:


    ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": <?php echo json_encode($block->getJsonConfig($option_txt)); ?>
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif;?>


<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery'],function($){
    var checkOption=<?php echo json_encode($checkOption);?>;
    var description=<?php echo json_encode($description);?>;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#attribute90").on('change',function(){
           var id= $(this).val();
           if(description[checkOption[id]])
           {
            //get child product description
           $('div[id="product.info.description"]').html(description[checkOption[id]]);
           }
           else{
            //if child product dont have description show , main product description
           $('div[id="product.info.description"]').html(description["product"]);

           }
        });

   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the images and the price will change.
More details can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to display the description of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing `description` and `short_description` for each simple product.

Switching `description` and `short_description` when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made `VCT Product Info Switcher` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem.